# How to make GitLab wiki public

Tags: gitlab

I know this is likely a “silly question” but if you could oblige me and give me a “silly” (correct) answer, that would be great.

How do I make GitLab wiki accessible to the public, so that anyone, even those not logged in, are able to see?

Thanks,
Connor

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project settings,  general, and change the project visibility to Public.

Comment: Is it possible to set the wiki to public, but not the repository?

Comment: @Joshua No, I don't believe so. If you want to do that, why not just create a separate project for the wiki?